# What is the effect of alpha particle on a diamagnetic substance?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Can alpha particles induce static charge on diamagnetic substances or temporarily magnetize when they are bombarded on them ? If yes then for how much of time the charge remains on it ?

Till what range do alpha particles travel when they are exposed to air ? (since they are short living)

Comment: you have a misunderstanding here, alpha pararticles are the nucleus of helium, it is a stable  particle and will gather two electrons and become a helium atom. It comes out in decays.

Comment: as for the range, look here http://www.srim.org/SRIM/SRIMPICS/STOPPLOTS.htm